# Attempting to save todo list using coredata doesnt save

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

Ive setup a tableview controller and am using it for a weight tracking list w/ coredata to save all of the entries made.  While everything works as far as adding entries and displaying them while the app is open, it's not displaying those entries on the next app load. I appreciate the help as im relatively new to swift coding.

[data model screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB5dd.jpg)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TodoViewController: UITableViewController {

    var items = [Items]()

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    var selectedCategory: Items?{
        didSet{
            loadItems()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    //MARK: Table View Datasource Methods
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Item", for: indexPath)
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
        cell.accessoryType = item.completed ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        items[indexPath.row].completed = !items[indexPath.row].completed
        saveItems()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == .delete){
            let item = items[indexPath.row]
            items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            context.delete(item)

            do{
                try context.save()
            }catch{
                print("Error deleting item with \(error)")
            }
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        var textField = UITextField()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Weight", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { (action) in

            let newItem = Items(context: self.context)
            newItem.name = textField.text!
            self.items.append(newItem)
            self.saveItems()
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addTextField { (field) in
            textField = field
            textField.placeholder = "Add Weight"
        }
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
    func saveItems(){
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch{
            print("Error Saving item with \(error)")
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func loadItems(){
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Items> = Items.fetchRequest()

        do{
            items = try context.fetch(request)
        }catch{
            print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update you items array to be of NSManagedObject

```
var items: [NSManagedObject] = []
```

Use this method for saving and call it from save action:

```
func save(name: String, completed: Bool) {
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
  return
}

let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Items", in: managedContext)!
let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
item.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")
item.setValue(completed, forKeyPath: "completed")

do {
  try managedContext.save()
  items.append(item)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
}
```

and for loading items, use this method:

```
func loadItems() {
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
  return
}

let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Items")

do {
  items = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
}
```

Then update cellForRowAtIndexPath method to be like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Item", for: indexPath)
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
    cell.accessoryType = item.value(forKeyPath: "completed") as? Bool ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}
```

Use KVC to access any attribute in array items like this:

```
item.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
```